# what is the method to retrieve the value that passed using an ajax call in cgi page

Tags: jquery, ajax, perl, parameters, cgi

Following is the starting of my process.cgi file :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;
#use CGI::Ajax;

#print "sddsdsd";
print header;
print start_html("Results");

use lib qw(.);
use Bugzilla;
use DbSlaveConnect;
#require "process_bug.cgi";
my $dbslaveconnect;
$dbslaveconnect = &DbSlaveConnect();

my $cgi = Bugzilla->cgi;
my $dbh = Bugzilla->dbh;
my $template = Bugzilla->template;
my $vars = {};
print "content-type: text/html \n\n";
print $cgi->param("value1");
```

following is my ajax code inside jquery :

```
var value1 = jQuery(this).find("INPUT").val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'process.cgi?'+value1,

    // The type of request.
    type: "get",

    // The type of data that is getting returned.

    error: function(){
        ShowStatus( "AJAX - error()" );

        // Load the content in to the page.
        jContent.html( "<p>Page Not Found!!</p>" );
    },

    success: function( data ){
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

following is my output :

[image]

i edited the first row, and i checked through the fire bug and found that the values are passing, but i can't retrieve that in my cgi page.what is the format of retrieving the value in the cgi page, following is my fire bug output :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

currently i tried to retrieve the value using the following format : 
    print $cgi->param("value1");

is any other packages are required in my cgi page to take the value, just like use CGI::Ajax.please help me???

Comment: Why `print "content-type: text/html \n\n";` near the end of your perl script when you start it off with `print header;`? Debugging stuff is *much* easier when you first remove the superfluous stuff that does nothing but get in your way.

Comment: why down vote??i have researched so many sites to find out the problem and discussed this with many people,but i didn't get a perfect solution that is why i put the question here. may be some one else will face the same problem.How can you say that it is not useful.??

Comment: How about stopping searching and asking and instead do some debugging? A good question's code is trimmed down to the essentials so people can easily read and reproduce. Two thirds of your Perl code, however, is completely unrelated to your question. DbSlaveConnect?

Answer (score 2):

Add a `data` setting to your `$.ajax()` call:

```
   var value1 = jQuery(this).find("INPUT").val();
   $.ajax({
       url: 'process.cgi',
       data : { 'value1' : value1 },
       type: "get"    
       error: function () {
           ShowStatus("AJAX - error()");

           jContent.html("<p>Page Not Found!!</p>");
       },    
       success: function (data) {
           alert('success');
       }
   });
```

When include this:

```
data : { 'value1' : value1 }
```

...it tells jQuery to add a parameter to the request with a parameter name `'value1'` and whatever value is in the `value1` variable.

The code that you had:

```
url : 'process.cgi?'+value1
```

...was adding the value the user entered directly to the query string without giving it a parameter name, so e.g., if they typed "test" you'd get this URL:

```
process.cgi?test
```

...when what you wanted was:

```
process.cgi?value1=test
```

Comment: :(values are passing, but it is not printing in the cgi page.And the output is showing in the process.cgi page itself

Comment: So you have tried my updated JS and it still doesn't work in your CGI?

Comment: yeah...i tried like that, still the value is not printing inthe cgi page

Comment: Sorry, I don't really do Perl CGI stuff, I mainly do Java-based server-side code, sometimes some .NET, though I'd guess something like `$cgi->param('value1')` would work if `$cgi` actually is the request. The change I've shown should at least fix the JS/jQuery side of things for you. Perhaps if you include more of your Perl CGI code in the question somebody else can help with that.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your Perl code locally, and it is correctly parsing the parameters out of a HTTP request. Therefore if it's not working at your end, it must be because your web page is not making a valid request.

What happens if you open a browser and just visit `http://localhost/process.cgi?value1=foo`

(You may need to change "localhost" to the server that you are testing this on.)

**Update:** As innaM points out in the comments, I should make it clear that I couldn't test the DbSlaveConnect section as I don't have access to that module. It's possible that the call to `DbSlaveConnect()` could be failing in some way.

Comment: So you have a version of `DbSlaveConnect`? Yes, the lines reading the CGI parameter should work, but only Jennifer_justin can know whether the other parts make that script go boom or not.